# Cannot enable Firestore for this project An unknown error occurred

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create fresh Firestore project from my Firestore console, but I get this error, anyone knows how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realized the issue was caused by my CORS(Cross-Origin Resource Sharing), so I turned it off and it got fixed.

Comment: Yes, It's correct. If CORS is enabled. Firebase may not work.

Comment: Thanks bro. You saved my night!

Comment: How to disable CORS ?

Comment: In my case it was uBlock Origin - Disabled it for the site and created Firestore database without an issue

Comment: @MuhammadTalha Just install the extension and disable it from there, however it should be disabled by default if you do not have the extension.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes there is a problem with the website, refresh the website.
It worked for me that way.

Comment: You are right. I have cors enabled. And I just did `clean cache and hard reload` and it worked.